# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT setup in prod

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud, credentials

Like to know what is the best practice to store or reference these GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT in prod?

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/Download/key.json"
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=`gcloud config get-value project
```

as in dev these are likely to be in .zshrc so when running:

```
poetry run python3 samples/snippets/quickstart/pub.py $PROJECT hello_topic
```

to publish message is fine and we can see messages inside console portal, however:

```
poetry run pytest samples/snippets/quickstart/quickstart_test.py
```

ERROR samples/snippets/quickstart/quickstart_test.py::test_pub - google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 User not authorized to perform this...

.zshrc have already set:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$HOME/Documents/python-pubsub/key.json"

export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=`gcloud config get-value project`
```

source .zshrc

Comment: The environment variables are intended for **development**. In production do not use them. Each compute service offers a service account that you can use for your applications. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#:~:text=A%20user%2Dmanaged%20service%20account,to%20access%20Google%20Cloud%20resources.

Comment: @john-hanley your comment should be the answer. In addition, perhaps add that the best practice is to create Service Accounts rather than use a service's default Service Account in order to specify a set of roles/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables are intended for development. In production do not use them.

Each **compute** service offers the ability to attach a service account. By default, **compute** services have a Google created service account (aka [Default Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default)) attached. Best practices recommend creating a User-managed service account with only the required IAM roles and attaching that to the service.

[User-managed service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed)

[Compute Engine Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

[Best practices for securing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts)